# HTML5 Video won't autoplay

Tags: html5-video

My browser is Chrome.  I know that to get it to autoplay, the attribute should just simply read "autoplay," but it isn't working.

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls autoplay preload="auto" width="620" height="350" data-setup="{}">
            <source src="http://x.com/something.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
            </video>
```

Comment: Hmm... Works fine with me, even with a wrong doctype... Can you play the video when clicking the button ?

Comment: Yeah, the video plays with a button click, but it doesn't automatically play for me.

Comment: Note: I've only tried this locally.  Does it need to be on the server?

Comment: Nope. I'm trying it and it works... It may be a chrome option ? (try with safari which is webkit too). You can also try a simpler version at first :
  <video controls autoplay width="620" height="350">
    <source src="...../.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

Comment: is this Chrome on desktop, or Chrome on a mobile device?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autoplay of HTML5 video doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482741/autoplay-of-html5-video-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers require the video to be initiated by the user or muted.

Try:

```
<video id="example_video_1" muted="muted" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls autoplay preload="auto" width="620" height="350" data-setup="{}">
            <source src="http://x.com/something.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
            </video>
```