# Autoplay of HTML5 video doesn't work

Tags: html, html5-video

I am not sure why autoplay function doesn't work on site.
Live site- http://lyorcohen.searchinteractions.com/ComingSoon/

```
<video class="supervideo hidden-phone hidden-tablet" poster="images/stillframe.jpg" autoplay>
<source src="video/WeaveLogo.mov" />
Your browser does not support the HTML5 video tag. Please upgrade it.
</video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works in Chrome but not in Firefox.

You also get this error in Firefox when the MP4 fails (due to testing this on an XP machine which does not support mp4 with Firefox):

> HTTP load failed with status 404. Load of media resource
>   http://lyorcohen.searchinteractions.com/ComingSoon/video/WeaveLogo.ogg
>   failed.

which means the fall-back fails due to the ogg file gone missing. Check that the file actually is there and that the name is spelled the same including capitalization.

On Chrome the MP4 video auto-plays and works fine.

You could also consider to provide a `webm` version of the file.

To eliminate further possible causes you can provide the type attribute in your source tags:

```
<source src="video/WeaveLogo.webm" type="video/webm" />
```

You are using the `autoplay` attribute correctly but some peculiar browsers has historically had problems with attributes without values so you can add `=true` to it to make these browsers happy (I can only think about one browser though...).

Comment: In 2019 it works in `Chromium` only sometimes! Writing not just `autoplay`, but `autoplay="true"` helps!

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problem when adding a video on a Magento site.  It seems that when I used the preload attribute before the autoplay attribute, it fixed the problem.  Was testing in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.autoplay = true;
vid.load();
```

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers require the video to be initiated by the user or muted.

Try:

```
<video class="supervideo hidden-phone hidden-tablet" poster="images/stillframe.jpg" muted="muted" autoplay>
<source src="video/WeaveLogo.mov" />
Your browser does not support the HTML5 video tag. Please upgrade it.
</video>
```

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227)